# Mixpanel tracking not working

Tags: javascript, mixpanel

I'm new to mixpanel and JS, and would like to know why is my script not working...
Any ideas?

```
<script>
    $('#tp_end_result').hover(function () {
        mixpanel.track("Hover Spot");
        console.log("Funciona");
    });
</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: In what way is it not working? Does your log statement show up in the browser console?

Comment: have you initialized Mixpanel? If so, could you please post the code where you initialize it?

Comment: Does mixpanel support to have events without custom params? 
If yes then I see only one possible reason why that couldn't work, some issue on initialization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The javascript code above is perfectly fine.

As you are not seeing any tracking for mixpanel, probably you might see the initialization code.

Just a quick recap, we need to import JS library into the HEAD tags, at the end of library, there is code of initialization of mixpanel:

mixpanel.init("YOUR TOKEN");

Here "YOUR TOKEN" should be replaced with token of respective project from you account. [See attached screenshot]

[image]

Please put your comments if still not works for you

Comment: Hi @vikram-jeet-singh js kill after submitting form

Comment: Jatinder, can you please elaborate more which form submission kills js. Is it mix panel or the js code implementation which initializes the mix panel lib

Comment: yes  http://api.mixpanel.com/track/ kills after form submit not getting mixpanel people in explore panel form submitting succesfully

Comment: it's been 4 years I hope you have changed your api keys and all else everyone knows them now